# MSQL to MYSQLI converter

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm not familiar with MySQLi

```
<?php
    $bestaat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM badgesdownload LIMIT 7");  
    while($bestaat2 = mysql_fetch_array($bestaat)) {
        $bestaat3 = $bestaat2['naam'];
        $txt = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM badgesdownload WHERE naam = '".$bestaat3."'"); 
        while($txt2 = mysql_fetch_array($txt)){
            $txt3 = $txt2['txt'];   
            echo $bestaat3; 
            echo'<br>';
            echo $txt3;
            echo'<br>';
        }
    }
?>
```

How can I change this script to mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

Mysqli - procedural method is fairly similar.  Just add your database connection as the first parameter to a query, and an 'i' in all the functions...

```
$bestaat = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM badgesdownload LIMIT 7");

while($bestaat2 = mysqli_fetch_array($bestaat)) {
    $bestaat3 = $bestaat2['naam'];
    $txt = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM badgesdownload WHERE naam = '$bestaat3'");
    while($txt2 = mysqli_fetch_array($txt)){              
        echo $bestaat3.'<br>'.$txt2['txt'].'<br>';
    }
}
```

I have also fixed some obvious errors.. ..missing close braces was the main one.

Comment: Hi, Sorry but the script is not working

Comment: Sorry but the code is still not working.

Comment: Its your code - I just converted it to mysqli_...  Whats not working?

Comment: The mysql code works, But the mysqli code not?

Comment: Have you named your database handle $db..?

Comment: Look this is working http://prntscr.com/7qfnr3

Comment: Comment your dbConnect function, and the call to it, execpt for the line starting with $link.  (This is your db handle.)  Change to mysqli_connect. Leave the mysqli_select_db line in as well. This also needs $link as the first parameter. Does this work now?

Comment: Look at the picture, Van you change it to mysqli? This script works namely

Comment: @TomLammers mate - we're here to help, but you have to help us to help you.  "It's not working" doesn't help me help you.  What error are you getting?

Comment: I see no error only a white page

Comment: So look in the error.log